# Conditional styling of an element in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am building a Windows phone 8 app that has a view model property of:

```
public bool IsReply {get; set;}
```

In my xaml code, I would like to distinguish two cases:

1. `IsReply=True`

   ```
   <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
   ...
   </Grid>
   ```
2. `IsReply=False`

   ```
   <Grid Margin="40,0,0,0">
   ...
   </Grid>
   ```

Basically, I would like to style the Grid element depending on the value of IsReply. I know that in WPF Style.Triggers exists, but apparently not in WP. 
The solution I have right now is to have a duplicate copy of the entire grid code and set the visibility of each to a data converter. However, I feel this should be simpler to do.

Comment: You should write your own `ValueConverter`: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/. Your converter should return [`Thickness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness(v=vs.110).aspx) struct instance.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I know this is old, but would you mind adding your comment as an answer instead?

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to use a Style with Triggers:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40 0 0 0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReply}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Im sorry, you're right. I was in the WPF context. Go with the converter, I've done this myself in WP8

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `margin` of the `grid` in your `MVVM`

```
<Grid Margin="{Binding margin}">
 ...
</Grid>
```

In your model

```
if(IsReply)
  margin = new Thickness("0,0,0,0");
else
  margin = new Thickness("40,0,0,0");
```

No need to create separate grids.

Comment: You shouldnt add View code in your ViewModel. The better way is to use a Converter as suggested in the question comment or a Style

Comment: Yeah, i was trying to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTrigger, but you have to add these two references (right click on References in your project and AddReference/Assemblies/Extensions/ ... ).

```
xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<Grid
    Margin="0">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <ei:DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding Path=IsReply}"
            Value="True">

            <ei:ChangePropertyAction
                PropertyName="Margin"
                Value="0" />

        </ei:DataTrigger>

        <ei:DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding Path=IsReply}"
            Value="False">

            <ei:ChangePropertyAction
                PropertyName="Margin"
                Value="40,0,0,0" />

        </ei:DataTrigger>

    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</Grid>
```